# log series of matrix

Tags: matrices

I need to prove the following inequality

$\log(I-A)<={\|A\|}/({1-\|A\|})$

expansion is same as reals.
i tried to apply triangular ineqality but i have a confusion if i can apply it to infinite series or not if yes then its easy .then we can apply ineqality and finally come at a infinite geometric series and that will sum up to write term.

But i am stuck at it ,can somebody help?

Comment: How do you define $\log(I-A)$?

Comment: It seems you'll need to assume $||A||<1$, right? The left hand side is an operator, the rhs is a real number. Do you want $||\log(I-A)||$ on the lhs?

Comment: Just use the expansion $-\log(I-A) = A + \frac12 A^2 + \frac13 A^3 \dots$, and apply the triangle inequality and the submultiplicity of the norm.  Is that what you meant by your proposed approach?  Also @WillNelson is correct.

Comment: yes $\|A\|\leq 1$ and it is $\|log(I-A)\|$     i am just confused is it ok to apply triangle inequality to an infinite series??do i need to assume something about convergence <i am not clear about it